# Division in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

What is the most natural generalization of division from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n $?

In fact my original question concerns any normed space $X$. How one can divide two vectors in $X$ ? However, question is still non trivial in $ \Bbb R^n $.

I want **at least**  this division be continuous w.r.t  the norm of $X$.

Motivation :

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two sequences in $X$, with $y_n$ be nice enough for all $n \in \Bbb N$. I want to find a good notion of division such that if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ then we get $$\frac{x_n}{y_n}  \to \frac{x}{y} $$

For example, this is possible in all $\Bbb R^{n^2}$, viewing its members as square matrices then if $\{y_n\} \subseteq \Bbb R^{n^2} $ be the sequence of non singular matrices, we have that conclusion!

Comment: It's only possible in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, no generalization.

Comment: We have four normed division algebras over $\Bbb R$. See (this page on WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras) you can also do it in $\mathbb{H} \cong \mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: @Fakemistake  I can define for you in $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ for all $n$

Comment: How do you define multiplication ?

Comment: Well, you can always define division componentwise. But then you have to deal with lots of vectors forbidden as divisors, namely every vector which contains a zero. For a better answer we need your definition of *division*. As stated above, only $\Bbb R, \Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^4$ can be made into division algebras.

Comment: @M.Winter That seems fine, can you generalize it to $X$?

Comment: @Ashkan Choose an isomorphism to some $\Bbb R^n$ and use the mentioned componentwise technique.

Comment: @M.Winter  $X$ might be infinite dimension !

Comment: @Ashkan You can still find a basis and hence an isomorphism to some real vector space, maybe an infinitely dimensional one.

Comment: @M.Winter So how the norm of $X$ plays role here ? What you are saying is possible for any vector space regardless the norm of $X$, so I doubt if we have $\frac{x_n}{y_n} \to  \frac{x}{y}$

Comment: Ashkan, you should say what properties you want *division* to have. Is division by $y$ supposed to be the inverse of multiplication by $y$? If YES, then what do you require from the multiplication. If NO, then we can simply define $x/y=x$ and be done with it. With that definition $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$ trivially imply $x_n/y_n\to x/y$.

Comment: Also observe that the notation $\dfrac x y$ is ambiguous. For example in your matrix division example there is a difference between division from the left and right. The matrices $Y^{-1}X$ and $XY^{-1}$ are not equal in general. Which one do you call $\dfrac X Y$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please look at my comment in Mikhail 's answer. I really want most natural one, which is continuous, You are right maybe my question was not expressed  as what I actually  mean. But really $\frac {x}{y} = x $ is not really natural.   

By $\dfrac x y$ I meant , considering  one well-defined way. Like $x y^{-1}$

Comment: Instead of matrices you always have the option to equate $\Bbb{R}^n$ with a ring like $\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ where $p(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $n$. The elements of this ring are invertible iff they have no common divisors with $p(x)$. So you can divide by a vector that is not in the union of some lower dimensional subspaces (compare to "non-zero determinant"). If $p(x)$ has no real zeros, then those forbidden subspaces have codimension two. This works for all even $n$. You can probably reach codimension four with a quaternionic construction (when you lose commutativity).

Comment: @Ashkan Ahh well, if you want to loose the field structure you are right. I didn't understand the part with the most natural generalization

Answer (score 2):

The question is really how *natural* you want your division/multiplication to be.  At the level of sets, $R$ and $R^n$ have the same cardinality so in that sense you can have a field structure on $R^n$ for any $n$ but it is not very interesting. As you pointed out, $R^{n^2}$ has a natural product structure as the matrix algebra and therefore also inverses (and "division" though you have to be careful about order) when the matrix is invertible.  The matrix algebra itself has some natural subalgebras, so you can get dimensions other than $n^2$ as well. Without clarifying what further properties you want such division to have the question is a bit vague.

Comment: I mostly care about  topological properties, and first  minimum condition that is really essential for my division,  is what I wrote as example, you may think division be continuous operator from $X \times X$ to $X$. But I really want it has other features of usual division!  That's  why I said the "most natural one " ... I considered some freedom for answerers to avoid of getting big NO , and IMPOSSIBLE .... like in first comment

Comment: Perhaps you may want to look at [H-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-space).